# How can I get the frame title from Emacs into the window bar of ConEmu?

Tags: emacs, conemu

I'm using ConEmu to run emacs (text-based) in a tab.  I'd like to have the frame title appear in the Window Title Bar much in the same way my PowerShell prompt does.

Has anyone gotten this to work? The standard ways of setting the frame title have not proved fruitful yet.

Thanks,
Larry

EDIT - screenshots added

[image: Pre-buffer eval:]

[image: Post-buffer eval and screen refresh:]

Comment: Don't know how emacs works. Is your frame title configurable? If so, you can use ANSI or GuiMacro to change tab out console title.

Comment: maximus - the frame title is configurable in emacs, as shown by @ThingOutsideTheBun, but i'm still having some issues.  GUIMacro may be too complex.

Comment: I believe, ThingOutsideTheBun shows right way to go. Thought, no need to send "\033]1;" but "\033]2;" is OK, it must change the window title. Also, you may use `concat "\033]9;3;" (yourtext) "\007"` to change tab title only.

Comment: @Maximus - no change....did the same thing

Comment: Wondering, why you not to describe what is ruined and what is not working?

Comment: I'll post a screenshot later and put the link to it.  Tough to describe.  Thanks for the push, Maximus.  It's been busy over here today :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to your emacs start-up file ($HOME/.emacs or $HOME/.emacs.d/init.el) and then reload it.

```
;; for buffer name to show in the term title
(defun xterm-title-update ()
  (interactive)
  (send-string-to-terminal (concat "\033]1; " (buffer-name) "\007"))
  (if buffer-file-name
      (send-string-to-terminal (concat "\033]2; " (buffer-file-name) "\007"))
    (send-string-to-terminal (concat "\033]2; " (buffer-name) "\007"))))
;;
(if (not window-system)
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'xterm-title-update))
```

Comment: partially worked.  it changed the frame title, but ruined the formatting in the rest of the emacs window.  i'm still trying.  thanks.

Comment: @larry - can you explain what is ruined?

Comment: See screen shots that were added to the original question

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Based on those two pictures above, could you describe in words what is not working. Also, it looks like you are using the native Windows version of emacs.

Comment: I'm running emacs as downloaded from http://gnu.spinellicreations.com/emacs/windows/.  As for the differences, the first window, prior to evaluating the buffer, I have colors, bars, etc.  After evaluating the elisp code, I lose "decoration" and proper window refreshes.